# How can I find the projection of an existing D3 path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I am using [D3](https://github.com/d3/d3) to render a vector map, based off of a GeoJSON dataset.

I have an existing path and I need to transform the path using a tween. To do this I need to use D3 to lookup the current `projection` object for this path. However, I can't seem to figure out the syntax to achieve this. Is it possible to look up the projection of an existing D3 path?

I can look up the path with:

```
const mapPath = d3.select('path.states');
```

But, I'm not sure where to go from there to get the projection object from this path. Thanks for any help or direction you might be able to provide.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by `projection`? You mean the values used in `d3.geo.projection`, or the data of the path?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to transform the existing path by `projection`, along the lines of this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3711652 . However, I don't have access to the projection as a persistent variable like in this example, so I'm trying to figure out how to look it up via D3.

Comment: If all you have is an SVG with `<path d="M....">` and you want to determine what projection was used to generate that path string (ie the value of the attribute **d**), then the answer is that it's not possible, or at best very difficult. It's equivalent to seeing a printed map and being able to tell what projection was used on it, but harder, because humans are (at the time of this writing :) better than AI.

Comment: Wondering why can't you hang on to the projection that was used to render it, or at least to the [`d3.geo.path`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Paths.md#path) that created the path (because if you have the latter, you can call `projection = myGeoPath.projection()`)? Is it because a different program rendered it?

Comment: It's probably not that difficult to store the original projection as a variable when the map is rendered. It would just be a bit easier to pull it out of D3 with select, _if_ it were easy and already there. Since it sound like it's not possible, I'll look into doing this outside of D3. @meetamit if you want to post an explanation as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer after a few more days. Cheers.

Comment: You could always store the projection as a `datum` of the path and then retrieve it when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since (based on the discussion in the comments) it sounds like the code that used a projection to render the map lives in the same app as the code that needs that projection elsewhere in the app, then this is really a question of app architecture — not projection detection. There are certainly ways to architect it such that the projection is "handed down" to the subroutine that need it, but that really depends on the frameworks and your implementation so far etc.

So without getting into architecture, another way to do this, is following Mark's suggestion (and in fact indicated by the code snippet in your original question) using d3's data binding to hang the projection off of the DOM node that the projection helped produce. IMO, compared with an app architecture solution, using data binding for this purpose is the lesser option, because it could make your code harder to follow bug prone. But it will work and, in a simple app at least, it's reasonable to do it this way. So...

Presumably, somewhere you have code that created and rendered the paths, and it might look something like this:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
var mapG = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'map');
var mapG.selectAll('path').data(myMapData).enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection));
```

I'm sure yours looks different, but hopefully it's close to the above, because I need to point out that the are N paths, corresponding to N entries in `myMapData`, and that each path already has a datum associated with it (the datum of the geo feature it represents). So a good place to hang your projection is NOT on the paths (because there are multiples, and they have have data bound to them already) but rather on the parent of the paths — `mapG` in this case. The way you do it is using `.datum()` to bind the projection to the DOM node:

```
mapG.datum(projection);
```

Now, from that **other** place in your code, where you need to look up the projection, you'd use `datum()` to extract it:

```
var mapG = d3.select('svg g.map')
var projection = mapG.datum()
```